# Wagtail blocks: accessing context and request in overridden get_context

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I trying to get the page and the request from context to be able to use pagination inside the block. The only context i get is

> context    {'self': None, 'value': None}

Is it even possible to have pagination inside a streamfield block?

```
class CustomStaticBlock(blocks.StaticBlock):


    def get_context(self, value):
        context = super(CustomStaticBlock, self).get_context(value)
```

Rendering with

```
{% include_block block%}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's now working (within `get_context`). If someone has the same issue with a `StreamField`, make sure to render it as:

`{% for block in page.body %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}`

The following won't work (empty `parent_context`):

`{% include_block page.body %}`

`{{ page.body|safe }}`

Comment: It worked for me to do `{% include_block page.body %}` too. I just couldn't do `{{ page.body }}` . Maybe this has changed since then.

Answer (score 4):

The context from the outer page is available within the block template, but unfortunately not within the `get_context` method. (This is due to the way the template context is built up - the result of `get_context` is [merged into the parent context](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/0e9c255b034ce4bdef5b265021833790fd813ed9/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/base.py#L237-L238).) This is a known limitation:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/2786#issuecomment-230416360
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2824

A possible workaround would be to override the `render` method (which is admittedly not ideal, because you'd have to repeat some or all of the existing `render` logic there).

Comment: But if we get this to work then? https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3032  ? I have added tests and legacy handling.